# OneSignal Notification Click Crashes App - ActivityNotFoundException

Tags: android, android-studio, ionic4, capacitor, onesignal

I have an Ionic app that uses OneSignal to send notifications to users. I have updated my project to use Android 12 (API level 32), which also required an upgrade of Capacitor to version 4:

```
ext {
    minSdkVersion = 22
    compileSdkVersion = 32
    targetSdkVersion = 32
    androidxActivityVersion = '1.4.0'
    androidxAppCompatVersion = '1.4.2'
    androidxCoordinatorLayoutVersion = '1.2.0'
    androidxCoreVersion = '1.8.0'
    androidxFragmentVersion = '1.4.1'
    junitVersion = '4.13.2'
    androidxJunitVersion = '1.1.3'
    androidxEspressoCoreVersion = '3.4.0'
    cordovaAndroidVersion = '10.1.1'
    coreSplashScreenVersion = '1.0.0-rc01'
    androidxWebkitVersion = '1.4.0'
}
```

Since the update, the app crashes whenever a user clicks/taps on the notification. The error reported is as follows:

[image]

Stack trace:

[image]

capacitor.build.gradle:

[image]

Android.Manifest.xml

[image]

I have added the android:exported="true" activity attribute as specified by the Capacitor upgrade guide.

Please advise why the app might crash when clicking on notifications?

Comment: Have you found any solution to this?
We are getting lots of crashes on our Capacitor Android platform as well.

Comment: @Ajan65 I have not resolved this yet, however, I have been in contact with the OneSignal team to try and get to the bottom of this, but priorities have changed for the moment. I will update this post as soon as I find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like OneSignal updated its documentation. compileSdk & targetSdkVersion 33 seems to be required. [docs](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ionic-sdk-setup#step-4-update-project-settings-to-target-android-13-android-only)

> Validate your target SDK version is at least version 33.

I'm guessing this was the culprit, will update here later.

Comment: Thanks, @Ajan65, I noticed this as well. Still got the error on API level 33. Latest recommendation from the OneSignal team was to "remove the OneSignal notificationClick Handler" and see if it works. Haven't gotten to it yet.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to replicate the issue. With ADB connected, I got the following error with more details than the one in Play Store.

Turns out it was an intent filter issue for us. On android we don't have an intent filter for launch URLs with link://, however, we were sending notifications with launch URLs starting with link://.

Solution is adding an intent filter at AndroidManifest.xml, under . Note that with that filter in place, you can open your with the intent filter you provide.

```java
    <activity
        android:exported="true"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|uiMode|layoutDirection"
        android:name="com.hediyesepeti.app.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBarLaunch"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <!-- Intent Filters For Opening App via URLS -->

        <!-- link://@URL -->
        <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="link"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.hediyesepeti.app, PID: 19178
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.hediyesepeti.app/com.onesignal.NotificationOpenedReceiver}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=link://www.hediyesepeti.com/... flg=0x10000000 }
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3676)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3813)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2308)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7898)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
     Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=link://www.hediyesepeti.com/... flg=0x10000000 }
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2161)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1805)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5470)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5428)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5926)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5893)
        at com.onesignal.OneSignal.openDestinationActivity(OneSignal.java:2443)
        at com.onesignal.OneSignal.handleNotificationOpen(OneSignal.java:2423)
        at com.onesignal.NotificationOpenedProcessor.processIntent(NotificationOpenedProcessor.java:116)
        at com.onesignal.NotificationOpenedProcessor.processFromContext(NotificationOpenedProcessor.java:64)
        at com.onesignal.NotificationOpenedReceiverBase.onCreate(NotificationOpenedReceiverBase.kt:36)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8290)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8269)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1384)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3657)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3813) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2308) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7898) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
```